# Include Files for autocompletion outside src-directory in Intelij

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

Intellij always index every file in my project to give me the best autocompletion-suggestions. But there is one probelm it only indexs the files from src - directory for autocompletion.

now i got some css styles from a node-module which i also want to get autocompletion-suggestions.

i could fix this with 2 bad solutions:

- by copying those css files directly inside the src
  dir. The problem is now that when the styles inside node modules gets
  updated the copyied files, didn't got there update.
- by marking the complete node_modules dir as src folder,
  but then i get autocompletion and Ctrl+Shift+N - suggestion also from
  this dir that should happen only for one specific node-module.

Can i tell intellij that it should also use those specifics files for autocompletion? And not only those from the src-folder?

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3

Comment: You might want to attach sources while browsing library code (not sure if CSS applies here), or add a symlink to your source directory.

Comment: how can i do that?